# CMake undefined reference to pthread_key_create

Tags: c++, multithreading, cmake

I have a CMake project. Here are some relevant lines:

```
    set(CMAKE_THREAD_PREFER_PTHREAD TRUE)
    set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG TRUE)
    find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
    message("[temp] threads stuff Threads_FOUND=${Threads_FOUND} in Threads_DIR=${Threads_DIR}")
    if(TARGET Threads::Threads)
      message("[temp] Yep")
    else()
      message("[temp] Nope")
    endif()
```

I can see in the console that the threads library is found and that the Threads::Threads target exists. But Threads_DIR is empty!

```
    [temp] threads stuff Threads_FOUND=TRUE in Threads_DIR=
    [temp] Yep
```

Some targets are linked to Threads::Threads.

```
add_executable(ETestOnline ETestOnline.cpp)

target_link_libraries(ETestOnline
  PRIVATE
    Threads::Threads
    ${extra_libs}
)
```

This is the output I get:

```
   [12/33] Linking CXX executable test/integration/ETestOnline
    FAILED: test/integration/ETestOnline 
    : && /usr/bin/clang++-9 -O2 -g -DNDEBUG  test/integration/CMakeFiles/ETestOnline.dir/ETestOnline.cpp.o -o test/integration/ETestOnline  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/opencv/lib:/opt/boost/lib  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-core.a  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-image.a  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-net.a  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-video.a  liblegofw_common_nodes.a  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-image.a  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.5  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-net.a  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-video.a  _deps/mycode-common-build/libmycode-common-core.a  /opt/boost/lib/libboost_random.so.1.70.0  /opt/boost/lib/libboost_system.so.1.70.0  _deps/spdlog-build/libspdlog.a  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavdevice.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavfilter.so  /opt/boost/lib/libboost_random.so.1.70.0  /opt/boost/lib/libboost_system.so.1.70.0  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.5  /opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.5 && :
    /usr/bin/ld: test/integration/CMakeFiles/ETestOnline.dir/ETestOnline.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
    //lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Any ideas what may be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The `target_link_libraries` command you show, is it really used? Have you rerun `cmake` to regenerate makefiles?

Comment: Yes ( to both questions)

Comment: It looks like the thread library is missing altogether from your linker output..

Comment: True, but I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Can you check if CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT is empty?

Comment: This variable is what is eventually passed to the linker. From reading the findthreads.cmake, this can be the case if your libc already provides threading functionality.

Comment: Yes, it is empty. That's quite interesting, what you are saying. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: It smells like you set a compiler in the `CMakeLists.txt` or do some other bad things. Please, prepare [mcve].

Comment: any updates on that, @SerbanStoenescu?